# Erro Code: 401() ao enviar notificação FCM usando um servidor

Tags: java, android, firebase, eclipse

**Estou com problema ao enviar notificação usando Firebase Cloud Messaging no Android. Estou utilizando o método abaixo:**

```
public void enviaNotificacao(String mensagem, Pedido pedido, String token) {
    Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);
    Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .addData("message", mensagem)
            .addData("pedido", getGson().toJson(pedido, Pedido.class))
            .build();
    try {
        Result result = sender.send(message, token, 3);

        System.out.println(result.getCanonicalRegistrationId());
        System.out.println(result.getErrorCodeName());
        System.out.println(result.getMessageId());
        System.out.println(pedido.getTokenGCM().substring(0, 10));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Aparece o erro seguinte:

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401()
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.makeGcmHttpRequest(Sender.java:484)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:215)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:182)
at com.t2ti.cardapio.Cardapio.enviaNotificacao(Cardapio.java:335)
at com.t2ti.cardapio.Cardapio.geraPedido(Cardapio.java:319)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Estou usando a Chave de API da Web disponibilizado nas configurações do firebase**

Comment: alguem pode me ajudar nisso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FONTE:** Traduzido de https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004418/10328310

Você deve dar uma olhada nos documentos do GCM onde explica a resposta do GCM: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#response e solucionando problemas do código de erro 401: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#auth_error

Descrição dos documentos:

```
 Erro de autenticação: A conta do remetente que você está tentando usar para enviar uma mensagem não pôde ser autenticada. Causas possíveis são:

 Cabeçalho de autorização ausente ou com sintaxe inválida.

 Número de projeto inválido enviado como chave.

 Chave válida, mas com o serviço GCM desativado.

 Solicitação originada de um servidor não listado na lista de permissões dos IPs da chave do servidor.
```

Por isso, verificaria se você está definindo o cabeçalho de autorização corretamente e se o número do Google Project está configurado corretamente com o GCM e aceitando o IP dos servidores.

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo segui o link [How to find Sender ID](https://dev.tapjoy.com/faq/how-to-find-sender-id-and-api-key-for-gcm/)

Eu estava colocando o token errado, mais agora estou com outro problema, o conteúdo da mensagem não aparece, segue um exemplo abaixo como estou usando o método de envio de notificação:

```
enviaNotificacao("Pedido recebido em nosso banco de dados", pedido, pedido.getTokenGCM());
```

aparece uma notificação vazia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Caso da Notificação em branco foi resolvido modificado o [RegistrationIntentService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

```
package com.t2ti.cardapiobalcao;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.Constantes;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.model.DetalheDenuncia;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // [START get_token]

            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Constantes.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Constantes.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Constantes.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        try {
            File arquivoXml = new File(getFilesDir(), "denuncia.xml");
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            DetalheDenuncia denuncia = new DetalheDenuncia();
            if (arquivoXml.exists()) {
                denuncia = serializer.read(DetalheDenuncia.class, arquivoXml);
            }

            denuncia.setTokenGCM(token);

            serializer.write(denuncia, arquivoXml);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("mytopic");
    }
    // [END subscribe_topics]

}
```